Date time error on SqlLab (Apache-superset) possible error in date/time operation
Have come across this error and stuck as to why it fails on SqlLab on apache superset
Error:

oracle error: ORA-01805: possible error in date/time operation

Query:
select to_timestamp_tz('20-NOV-2024 01.00 AM UTC','DD-MON-RR HH:MI AM TZR')
from dual;

The query runs fine in SQL*PLUS / SQLcl tools.
Apache-superset ver: 2.1.0
